# Understanding shorthand closure syntax for map function in Swift

Tags: swift, functional-programming, closures

I'm trying to understand some of the short hand syntax used by the map function.

The following is the setup

```
    let array = [1, 2, 3]

    // these make sense
    let arr1 = array.map({String($0)})
    let arr2 = array.map{String($0)}
    let arr3 = array.map({ number in
        return String(number)
    })
    let arr4 = array.map({ (number) -> String in
        String(number)
    })
```

Here is where the confusion lays. In swift I can forgo the curly braces for map, but this seems like something that can't be done, for my own functions where I have a trailing closure. Some magical inference that's being made perhaps? Also why is the String initialized in this way?

```
    // this doesn't make sense. Foregoing the curly braces? I can't do that!!!
    let arr5 = array.map(String.init)    
    let arr6 = array.map(String())    // Compile Error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '@noescape (Int) throws -> _'
```

This is me trying to use similar syntax as map

```
func crap(block:(Int)-> String) {
    print("Int to string block" + block(1));
}
// works obviously
crap{ "\($0) some garbage" }
// compile error : Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure
crap( "\($0) some garbage" )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Distinguish parentheses `()` from curly braces `{}`.

In a sense, only the parentheses version is "real", because, after all, that is what a function call requires. In the parentheses when you call `map`, you put a function. It may be a function *reference* (i.e. the name of a function):

```
    let arr = [1,2,3]
    func double(i:Int) -> Int {return i*2}
    let arr2 = arr.map(double)
```

Or it can be an anonymous function, meaning a function body in curly braces:

```
    let arr = [1,2,3]
    let arr2 = arr.map({$0*2})
```

But in *that* case, and that case only, you can (as a shortcut) use the "trailing closure" syntax instead:

```
    let arr = [1,2,3]
    let arr2 = arr.map(){$0*2}
```

But since `map` takes no other parameters, you can then *also* omit the parentheses — the only situation in Swift where you can call a function without parentheses:

```
    let arr = [1,2,3]
    let arr2 = arr.map{$0*2}
```

Comment: Oh I'm a dummy. I went down an erroneous path that thought I could widdle down a block to a function call. Okay Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger this shorthand syntax quickly from the keyboard?

Comment: The other thing that might be obvious to some, but should be noted, is that `String.init` works with map because it's a reference to a function without calling it— so the same type of thing you get when you create an anonymous closure.  You can think of this in Swift as it giving you a function as a closure when you use the name of a function without parentheses.  And also, for initializers you have to use `TypeName.init` instead of `TypeName` or `TypeName()` to make the syntax clear (otherwise, the compiler will think you're asking for the type not a function, or calling it right there).