# comparing time without date swift3

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

I am using an API to get a list of times which is five times a day as string in (AM,PM) format without date,

("4:30 AM","1:00 PM","3:20: PM","6:40 PM","9:10 PM")

what I am trying to do is to show the next time in the screen depends on the current time on the iPhone

so if the time now is 5:00 PM the time should display on the screen is 6:40 PM

how can I compare times in swift without including the dates because I tried to convert the list of times I have to Date type but unfortunately am getting dates and the dates shows in 2001 so even if I try to compare the date would give me wrong result

```
 print(self._praytime.arraytime)




            for Dates in self._praytime.arraytime {
                let dateformatters = DateFormatter()
                dateformatters.dateStyle = .none
                dateformatters.timeStyle = .short
                let xxbbs = dateformatters.date(from: Dates)
                print(xxbbs!)
            }
```

after I got the times I put it in Array and I tried to execute the code upper so I can get the times without the date but what shows in the output screen was this

```
Optional(2000-01-01 11:14:00 +0000)
Optional(2000-01-01 20:06:00 +0000)
Optional(1999-12-31 23:57:00 +0000)
Optional(2000-01-01 03:11:00 +0000)
Optional(2000-01-01 04:41:00 +0000)
```

any idea how to solve this problem and if is there any other easy way to do this task I'm exciting to hear it

thank you all

Comment: You can use `(NS)DateComponents` that you'll help match the year/month/day with the target date. Then, you can form each of "attach" each of theses dates with the hours/min ones.

Comment: Why are you trying to work with `Date`? A time is not a date. Convert the time string into an integer representing number of minutes.

Comment: thank you @rmaddy for you response if I follow you idea how can i handle the AM PM , if conditions ?

Comment: That would be part of parsing the time string and calculating the proper integer value. Basically, if AM, do nothing, if PM, add 12*60 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion using `DateComponents`

- Assuming this given array

  ```
  let times = ["4:30 AM","1:00 PM","3:20 PM","6:40 PM","9:10 PM"]
  ```
- Create a date formatter matching the format

  ```
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
  ```
- Map the time strings to `Date` and immediately to `DateComponents` considering only `hour` and `minute`

  ```
  let dateArray = times.map { Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from:formatter.date(from:$0)!) }
  ```
- Map this array to the next date from now matching the components respectively

  ```
  let upcomingDates = dateArray.map { Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: $0, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!  }
  ```
- Sort the array ascending, the first item is the date you are looking for

  ```
  let nextDate = upcomingDates.sorted().first!
  ```
- Use the formatter to convert the date back to a time string

  ```
  print(formatter.string(from:nextDate))
  ```

Comment: thank you so much , its working fine . I have a question am new to swift and I did not understand what is the benefit of (map) . is it to just mapping the current time with the time am getting from the array so both have the same format ? in Calendar nextDate working also with times only without dates ? if you have a link or any other source for map that will help me a lot thank

Comment: what is $0 @vadian in the map syntax ?

Comment: @IOS777 Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493802/understanding-shorthand-closure-syntax-for-map-function-in-swift

Comment: `map` transforms the items in an array from one type into another, $0 is the placeholder for *current item*.