# Swift : Map function found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, time, dateformatter

I'm trying to compare times, following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43958003/7675202), but it crashes on me. I have literally the same codes but it keeps crashing on the `dateComponents` line or the `sorted()` line depending on where I put the function.

```
func setCurrentTime(times: [String]) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h: mm a"

    let timeMap = times.map {
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: formatter.date(from: $0)!)
    } // Crashes here ...

    let upcomingTIme = timeMap.map {
        Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: $0, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
    }

    print(upcomingTime) // Returns []

    let nextTime = upcomingTIme.sorted().first! // Crashes here too, error line shown below

    print(nextTime) // Doesn't get printed...
}
```

ERROR:

```
[]
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

If I pass in an array or hardcode an array in the function it still crashes.

Comment: Date format should be “h:mm a”

Comment: Tthe dateformatter can’t parse the input with the format you have given, so it returns `nil` and because you have force unwrapped the result, you get a crash. If you fix your format string it will probably work, but is more defensive to use `flatmap` to filter the optionals and avoid force unwrapping

Comment: Could you mention what's the passed `[String]`? it would be more clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash that you are getting is due to difference in the format for passed value and format used in date formatter.

```
formatter.dateFormat = "h: mm a"
```

While your formatter uses space between **'h:'** and **'mm'** and you may have passed data as below. ( without the space between 4: and 30 in 4:30 AM

```
let times = ["4:30 AM","1:00 PM","3:20 PM","6:40 PM","9:10 PM"]
```

Date formatter will not return valid date and you have used '!' operator which result in crash.

Either you can change the date-format or pass data according to format. This will solve the issue and you will get

- **This is timemap**

[hour: 4 minute: 30 isLeapMonth: false , hour: 13 minute: 0 isLeapMonth: false , hour: 15 minute: 20 isLeapMonth: false , hour: 18 minute: 40 isLeapMonth: false , hour: 21 minute: 10 isLeapMonth: false ]

- **This is next date**

2017-10-01 13:10:00 +0000

- **This is upcoming date**

[2017-10-01 23:00:00 +0000, 2017-10-02 07:30:00 +0000, 2017-10-02 09:50:00 +0000, 2017-10-01 13:10:00 +0000, 2017-10-01 15:40:00 +0000]

Comment: Ah, I noticed that silly mistake. But now I can't unwrap it? It comes out as `Optional(2017-10-02 10:10:00 +0000)`. Also, it doesn't show the next time I don't know where the `10:10` is coming from when the array is `["6:10 AM", "1:45 PM", "4:50 PM", "7:02 PM", "8:50 PM", "1:30 PM"]`

Comment: Actaully, nevermind! Fiddling with the code I finally understood how it works! Thanks!!