# Swift syntax explanation with compact map

Tags: swift, higher-order-functions

I did find following code while examine code:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        return super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)?
            .compactMap { $0.copy() as? ParallaxLayoutAttributes }
            .compactMap(prepareAttributes)
    }

    private func prepareAttributes(attributes: ParallaxLayoutAttributes) -> ParallaxLayoutAttributes {
        // Lot of code doing stuff with attributes 
        return attributes
    }
```

So, actually what i want to ask is, that compact is function declared as following:

```
@inlinable public func compactMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
```

Here in example, we pass just function, without arguments:

```
.compactMap(prepareAttributes)
```

That completely bend my mind, because, well, `prepareAttributes` function declared like this (with argument you have to pass):

```
private func prepareAttributes(attributes: ParallaxLayoutAttributes) -> ParallaxLayoutAttributes
```

So, why code above compiles and what how exactly  `.compactMap(prepareAttributes)`
runs when you did not pass an argument for `prepareAttributes` function?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/37493802/1187415.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the call `.compactMap(prepareAttributes)`, you pass in the function, `prepareAttributes` to `compactMap` as a closure. Since `prepareAttributes` takes a single input argument whose type matches the closure variable of `compactMap`, the compiler can automatically infer that it needs to pass `$0` to `prepareAttributes`.

So essentially, `.compactMap(prepareAttributes)` is shorthand for

```
.compactMap {prepareAttributes(attributes: $0) }
```

A simple example of the same behaviour with `map` that is quite often used is to `map` over a type that you then pass into an init, which you could write as `.map { MyType(input: $0) }` or simplify to `.map(MyType.init)`.

```
struct MyInt {
    let value: Int

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let ints = [1,2,3]
let myInts = ints.map(MyInt.init) // same as `ints.map { MyInt(value: $0) }
```

Comment: The tricky bit here is that compactMap takes a single parameter, which is a _closure_. A function is actually a type of closure. By passing in the name of a function, you tell compactMap to generate calls to your function, passing in objects from the source collection as parameters to that function, and expect objects of a new type to be returned.

Comment: @DuncanC that is what I was trying to get to as well, but I guess your explanation is more clear :)

Comment: That's great and thanks for detailed answer :) I wonder where i can find all of those syntaxis "shorthands", that "shorten" the code, because sometimes it looks kind of confusing

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban you're welcome. Sadly most of these are "hidden" gems, there's usually no documentation around them.

Comment: Apple's Swift iBook covers closure syntax in-depth, and most of the different ways you can shorten invoking/passing a closure. I seem to remember it covering this case, but it's been a while since I read it. I suggest looking there)

Comment: It's confusing for sure, and hard to explain clearly.